# Order a DQL Join by count on assiociation

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a DQL query likes this:

```
$dql = "SELECT p, count(u.id) as ucnt FROM IAA\Entity\Project p " .
       "JOIN p.likedByUsers u ORDER BY ucnt";
$query = $this->_em->createQuery($dql);
```

Question is, how can I hold on to sorting by count, but NOT get them in result? I want to get only projects sorted by count, not array with [project] and [ucnt].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from Doctrine 2.2 [(source)](http://www.michelsalib.com/2012/03/doctrine2-ninja-with-the-hidden-keyword/) :

```
SELECT a, COUNT(b.id) AS HIDDEN c [...] ORDER BY c
```

Comment: I will try it, as for now my solution was to add a counter to the entity and then order by it, but HIDDEN looks much more nicer :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```php
$dql = "SELECT p FROM IAA\Entity\Project p " .
       "JOIN p.likedByUsers u ORDER BY count(u.id)";
$query = $this->_em->createQuery($dql);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried, it gives an error: Message: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 72: Error: Expected end of string, got '('

Comment: But in this case you can select 2 values and after that ignore count value in PHP code.

Comment: I cant, beacose it returns syntax error. I know I can reorder the array in PHP but this does not seems an elegant solution, there must be way to fetch only proejcts without the count still having them ordered by it.